# Software for drawing ROC curve

Tags: machine-learning, roc

Having the `sensitivity` and `specificity` values, what software do you recommend that enables drawing the `ROC` curve provided this data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As I [wrote earlier](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13636/how-to-draw-an-roc-curve/13639#13639), ROC requires confidence scores, not random FPR/FNR readings.

Nevertheless, I would recommend two R packages: [ROCR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROCR/index.html) for plotting (many options, very nice graphs) and `colAUC` from [caTools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caTools/index.html) for calculating AUROC (rocket fast).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can I find the confidence score, provided as I mentioned that I have `sensitivity` and `specificity` values for different studies? Thanks

Comment: @SWEngineer Depends on the method you use; vote proportion in ensembles, distance from boundary in SVM-likes, proportion of classes in the neighborhood in kNN-likes, ...

Comment: What I have is a list of studies that used some sort of computer algorithm or computer aided diagnosis (CAD) system and measured the `sensitivity` and `specificity`. So, as you can imaging I JUST have values for those two variables for different studies, and trying to plot an `ROC` curve. Provided that, what should I do to get an ROC curve correct? Thanks

Comment: In this case there is no hope for ROC. You can at most plot them as points to compare with other ROC curves.

Comment: I will be having the following values in this case `TP`, `FP`, `FN`, and `TN`. Do you think this is sufficient. There is a software called `Meta-DiSc` that requires those values to draw a `SROC` curve. By the way, is there a difference between `SROC` and `ROC`? Thanks

Comment: I have read this [Meta-DiSc paper](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2288/6/31) and it seems that this sROC is a ROC *approximation* obtainable from several spec/sens readings from different studies (as in your data). The precise algorithm of that sROC is described [in this paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8210827?dopt=Abstract).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the previously mentioned packages, an other R package I would recommend to perform ROC Analysis and draw ROC curves is [pROC](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pROC/index.html). This package can perform multiclass AUC as defined by Hand and Till (2001).

Answer (score 0):

For MATLAB, there are some basic tools on my website [here](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/matlab/#roc)