# Tutorials for drawing an ROC curve

Tags: roc, curves

Are there tutorials you recommend that teach how to draw an `ROC` curve?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to be more precise. Do you want to draw them by hand (don't), or use a specific piece of software (R, SPSS, ...)? What exactly is your problem with drawing them?

Comment: See my [answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13636/how-to-draw-an-roc-curve) to your previous question -- I think it is a pretty straightforward description of ROC.

Comment: The most important thing to learn is WHEN to draw ROC curves. 95% of the examples that I have seen are unnecessary and do not represent the best approach to the problem.

Comment: @Nick Sabbe. Since I'm trying to learn how to plot an `ROC`curve, a tutorial to show you the steps and how it is built would be fine, but I will surely use a software for that. Thanks

Comment: _Programmers’ Niche_ in [this document](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2004-1.pdf), p.33, would be a great read.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to learn how to draw ROC curves by hand, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) is a good place to start.
If you just want to calculate a plot a ROC curve, and don't really care to learn how the math works, try the [colAUC funcion](http://www.oga-lab.net/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=caTools%3acolAUC) in the [caTools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caTools/index.html) package in [R](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=CRAN).

I believe most major stats packages can drawn ROC curves as well, and a little googling should help you find the appropriate commands.